# Maven install with CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, integration-testing

I have a SpringBoot console application AbcApplication which implements the CommandLineRunner interface.

I encountered a problem that the run method of AbcApplication always gets executed when I run my unit test. I Google around and fixed this by putting `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on my test class and `@Profile("!test")` on my AbcApplication.

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class AbcApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeTest {
```

Now, however, if I use Maven install (using IDE GUI) to build my jar, the run method of AbcApplication will again always get executed the build will just be stuck there. I can toggle the "skip test" for the build to work but I do want to run the test before the build.

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: the `run` method will get executed for inegration test cases right ? so you don't want integration test cases ?

Comment: I found out that the build stuck because I have one integration test class that's empty (a placeholder, haven't wrote the test). Yes I do want the integration test case but I thought it's causing the build to be stuck so I tried to exclude them. That was my wrong way of solving the problem.